# Unable to type an 's' in the terminal

Tags: pi-4

I am presently trying to install Orca on a RPI4, and have a strange problem. When I open a terminal session, every time I hit an 's' I hear "Speech Enabled" or "Speech Disabled" but I can't actually get an 's' on the command line. Makes it very hard to type 'sudo' or any other command. Any idea why I have this behavior? And, how to get rid of it!

Comment: Have you tried another keyboard?  Sounds like a hardware problem.

Comment: Or sounds like "s" has been mapped to a macro or something.  When you say "terminal session" exactly what are you running and how did you start it?  And is the keyboard connected directly to the RP, or are you using SSH, VNC, X-Windows to connect to it?  If so, what kind of computer/setup are you using to connect?

Comment: Keyboard is directly connected (USB) to the RPI4.  I do have Orca turned on (this is for my wife, and she is blind...) so the (INSERT-s) is a valid key mapping to turn the speech on or off, but not just 's' by itself.  got me stumped!

Comment: Copy and paste 's'?

Comment: @CharlesEdmondson The suggestion to paste in a few "s" is valid.  Trying it.  I assume when Orca is enabled or disabled it says "Speech Enabled/Disabled" as indicated.  If so, Orca is certainly at play here.  Maybe turn Orca off to verify that.  I'd try googling Orca forums (assuming they have some) . . . seems like a very app-specific issue.  I googled enough to discover the expected key sequence is Alt+Windows+s . . . very odd.  I've never heard of Orca until today.  Cool app.